# How do I publish my project on Azure websites containing executable files

Tags: executable, publish, azure-web-app-service, rotativa

In my project I'm using Rotativa.dll to generate my PDF reports, it turns out that running the project locally everything works fine, but when I publish my site on Azure WebSites'm not getting. How do I publish an executable file in Azure?

Is there some setting for this?

Answer (score 0):

You can publish any executable you want to an azure site. There is no limitation on the type of assembly you publish.

However there are some APIs that you can't call from an Azure Website for example GDI APIs.
I am not familiar with Rotativa.dll but since you say it's for PDF processing there is a very good chance it's using GDI APIs.